# Is my transcription of the handwritten kanji correct?

Tags: kanji, katakana, handwriting, writing-identification

[image]

I just want to make sure my transcription is correct of the sentence pictured. (it probably isn't, but this is really the closest I could come up with.)

読みとみバーグアフ。微妙...

Is that correct?

[image]

For the second picture, I think the transcription should be: サターンのマルコソみだいなｘｘ with the ｘｘ being doodles most likely. For a while I thought the first ｘ was ミ and then the two ｘｘ could have been です, but I'm pretty sure it's just doodles.

Comment: Are you calling any type of Japanese writing 'kanji'?

Comment: @l'électeur no, before I edited the post to add the second photo, I wasn't very clear but I was also asking if the kanji I transcribed was also correct due to the unclear handwriting.

Comment: Where are you getting these images?  Given that your screenshots appear to show your entire desktop, and that your other icons are sharp and clear, it seems that the images of the handwriting are just crappy resolution.  Is there any way you could get higher-quality images?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi the files were just stuff I found online a long time ago super zoomed in. I don't even remember where I got them, just that I wanted to use them to practice my Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the first one is (furigana added):

> 読【よ】み込【こ】みバーグラフ. 数秒【すうびょう】...

The second is harder for me to read.  Here's my guess:

> サターンの
>     マルコン
>     みたいな
>     x x x x

The サターンのマルコン makes sense given the image.  See also [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%B5%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%22).

<s>That last word is a smudge.  It appears to end in シー, possibly ミー.  The first two kana are ... ???</s>

Any more context you could provide would help.

⇒ Naruto in the comments points out that the last word is カンジ.  The 濁点【だくてん】 or 〃 mark on the シ looked like a separate character and a single line ー to me, which threw me off.  Thank you, @naruto!

Comment: Thank you so much. It's supposed to be an artbook page detailing stuff about a cellphone. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: `サターンのマルコンみたいなカンジ` ("Something like [Saturn's Multi Controller](https://sega.jp/fb/segahard/ss/multi.html)") ですね

Comment: Thank you @naruto!